# Retrieving values from nested collection

Tags: java, collections

I have Map inside List as below :

```
List<Map<String, Object>> migrationMap = new LinkedList<Map<String, Object>>();
```

I want to display the values of list "migrationMap".

Could anyone help me out

Comment: Though it's a list you have to specify index like `migrationMap.get(0).values()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every map implements the `values()` method, which returns a collection of all values contained in the map, see [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()). Knowing this, you can iterate over the list of maps and then over the values returned by `values()` to print these:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> migrationMap = new LinkedList<Map<String, Object>>();
for(Map m: migrationMap){ // For every element in the list
    for(Object v: m.values()){ // For every value that is stored in this list element’s map
        System.out.println(v.toString()); // Print that value
    }
}
```

If, for instance, you want to perform a test on the values to be printed, or otherwise manipulate them, you can use the [keySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) method to get a collection of all keys in the map.

```
for(Map m: migrationMap){ // For every element in the list
    Set<String> keys = m.keySet(); // Get a set of all keys in the map
    for(key: keys){ // For every key in said set
        Object value = m.get(key); // Retrieve the object referenced by this key
        System.out.println(m.get(key)); // Print it
    }
}
```